# Masonry Gallery Layout with No Gaps

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, masonry, packery

I would like to create a masonry gallery, but have no gaps in between images. I have tried masonry(leaves gaps), isotope(leaves gaps), and packery(seems to do what I want, but leaves staggered images at bottom of layout).

For example,

I want to have a square of images. Lets say 1000x1000. In that I want to have images of all different sizes fit in the layout.

Does anyone know how to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `$.masonry()` doesn't leave gaps. Remove gaps from your CSS, make sure your image widths match so everything *can* be flush side by side, and be sure not to specify a gutter or width in your masonry configuration that will create space between elements.

```js
$('.masonry').masonry();
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry">
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg">
  <img src="https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg">
  <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/08/22/006F877400000258-3482989-image-a-10_1457476109735.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2016/03/ultraviolet_image_shows_the_sun_s_intricate_atmosphere/15891756-1-eng-GB/Ultraviolet_image_shows_the_Sun_s_intricate_atmosphere_node_full_image_2.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Now the only thing that I need to still try and fix is the bottom part of the grid. If you look, the last image on the left is a bit farther down then the right side of the of the gallery. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @jesders88 the heights of the images will need to match or add up math-wise so everything is flush along the bottom edges. If you're mixing/matching heights and widths randomly, odds are things won't align well without stretching or cutting off parts of the images.

Comment: That makes more sense. I was trying to figure out a way to see if the browser could detect and fit the dynamic width/height ranges to all fit in a square. That could be some tricky math :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jesders88 np, nope masonry won't make everything match like that for you, but it isn't that hard to figure out the math of the layouts to make it work. Though trying to make a bunch of random/different sized images a perfect 1x1 grid with a bunch of breakpoints (where masonry does a re-layout) will likely be some work.